# Assets Not Loading in Rails App

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, assets, production-environment

first question and a rails newly (so  take it easy on me)...

It appears my rails application is not loading it's assets in production, I have searched endlessly and tried nearly every suggestion and I have had no such luck.

At this point, I do not even know what information to provide to help anyone diagnose the problem so here is my github like: https://github.com/jz-ziegler/develapp

Let me now if anything else is needed, thanks!

Comment: "Not loading" means what, exactly? What sort of URLs do you see in your rendered pages? Are the files missing? Have you properly created the assets during your deployment procedure with `rake assets:precompile`?

Comment: "not loading" meaning when i am in production my fonts (from google fonts) are not loading and my glyphicons are showing up as little squares...both the fonts and glyphicons are loading in development.  The files are not missing and yes I have properly created assets with rake assets:precompile.